# ¿Cómo ejecutar un Asyntask una por una?

Tags: java, android, webservice, android-asynctask

Busco una vez más de su ayuda,
tengo un determinado número de `Asyntask` para ejecutar,en este caso son dos diferentes tareas, una es para guardar y la otra para actualizar, el detalle que ocupo es que se ejecuten una por una.

Una muestra del código que utilizo es la siguiente:

```
    int id = 0;
    int id2 = 0;
    String  mqry = "select * from objeto where UpdateToServer = 1";
    Cursor crp = db.rawQuery(mqry,null);
    if(crp.getCount() > 0){
        while(crp.moveToNext()){
            id = crp.getInt(crp.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            id2 = crp.getInt(crp.getColumnIndex("id2"));
            if(id2 == 0){
                SaveObjeto sObj = new SaveObjetor();
                sObj.execute(id);
            }else {
                UpdateObjeto uProd = new UpdateObjeto();
                uObj.execute(id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Así es como ejecuto todas las que deseo, en este caso que un campo tenga 1 en base de datos.

Estuve leyendo e investigando un poco y encontré una clase que posiblemente haga lo que deseo pero no la entiendo muy bien
[Clase Executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)
¿Quien la ha utilizado????

Comment: Mark, te refieres a que SaveObjeto() es un Asynctask y UpdateObjeto() es otro y quieres que sean secuenciales? =0-

Comment: asi es son Asyntask y dependiendo el numero de registros encuentre en la base de datos se ejecutaran guardar o actualizar

Comment: pero en este código nunca se van a ejecutar ambas operaciones, estan en condiciones excluyentes en un if. Tu objetivo es que el loop se congele hasta que alguna de las 2 termine?

Comment: alguna sugerencia que puedas dar amigo??? @jirungaray

Comment: La documentación de [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) menciona el tema de orden de ejecución depende de la versión. También podría serte de utilidad el método `executeOnExecutor` que se le puede pasar como parámetro `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` para que la ejecución sea serial.

Comment: @MarkDev Tu objetivo es que el loop se congele hasta que alguna de las 2 termine y luego pasar al proximo item?

Comment: Si, en si busco que no se ejecuten en paralelo y sea el loop o asyntask

Comment: @MarkDev una pregunta mas, esos AsyncTask modifican la UI al terminar_

Comment: no solo envian info a un webservice...

Answer (score 2):

En tu caso no serviría un Executor ya que tendrías que envolver cada iteración del loop dentro de una tarea en sí para poder ordenarlo.

Tu caso es en realidad mucho más simple, usando [AsyncTask.get()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) se congela el hilo actual hasta que el AsyncTask devuelva el resultado.

**Importante:** no llamar esto desde el hilo principal(UI) de la app ya que esto puede bloquearse por varios segundo y causar un ANR.

EDIT: Agrego un ejemplo a pedido de @webserveis, en realidad es muy simple:

```
new DownloadFilesTask().get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

va a llamar a mi Asyctask exactamente igual que si llamara

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute()
```

Con la diferencia es que el get va a detener el hilo actual ( en este caso, con un tiempo limite de 5 segundos) hasta que el Task complete su ejecución, en esencia estas convirtiendo la tarea en sincrónica.

Comment: interesante lo que comentas, tienes algun pequeño ejemplo de uso?

Answer (score 1):

si buscas que tus Asynctask sean secuenciales lo creo que lo correcto sería usar un único Asynctas o Thread el cual realice las 2 tareas, estas se realizarian secuencialmente.

Comentare algo que puedes ver en la documentacion acerca de [Asynctask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), cuando se agrego esta clase al SDK inicialmente se ejecutaban en serie en un mismo thread, pero cuando se introdujo el sistema operativo 3.0 [Honeycomb](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#HONEYCOMB) se permitia ya el ejecutarse en paralelo.

Este precisamente es un metodo que realizamos para dicha tarea, esto para obligar no importando el sistema operativo se ejecutaran en paralelo>

```
public static void runParallelAsyncTask(AsyncTask task){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        task.execute();
    }else{
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
}
```

Si deseas que se realicen en serie puedes usar en lugar de [THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) usar [SERIAL_EXECUTOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR)

Para lo que deseas puedes usar el metodo **[.get()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get())** para obligar a detener tu programa hasta que termine la ejecucion del [Asynctask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()), pero esto provocara que se detenga la UI seguramente, considero que seria mejor opcion para lograr que sean secuenciales, tener un unico Asynctask y agregar la ejecucion de las tareas dentro del mismo.